# Checkbox TwoWay binding

Tags: c#, checkbox, data-binding, binding, two-way-binding

I have a listbox bound to a list. The list contains checkboxes bound to a field/member of the list. What I want to achieve is that I want to delete the data from list when it's corresponding checkbox is checked.

Here's my xaml code:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding histList, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="197" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding FilterName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here's the code in the .cs file

```
namespace ReportsUIScreens
{
    public partial class EditStyle : ChildWindow
    {
        private List histList;
        public EditStyle(List histListLink)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            histList = histListLink;
            this.ListBox1.ItemsSource=histList;
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //HERE'S WHERE I WANT TO DELETE
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }
        .........
        .........
        .........
    }
}
```